# Local installation of Magento 2 doest not generate files in the pub/static folder

Tags: magento2, magento-community, .htaccess, localhost, mamp

I've just installed Magento 2 Community Edition with sample data (downloaded from their website and not installed with composer) locally via MAMP. The installation process was succesful, but all files in the pub/static folder are missing except .htaccess. That means all css, js etc. return 404 for both frontend and backend.

I've spent several hours trying to fix this without luck. This is what I've done so far:

- Changed `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride` from 'None' to 'All' in the /MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf and restarted MAMP
- Made sure `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is uncommented in httpd.conf
- Set up a development domain (magento.dev) in MAMP
- Tried running `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` in the magento.dev root using Terminal. This however returns:

> Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento.dev/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php
>   on line 64

- Uncommented and changed RewriteBase to `RewriteBase /` in the .htaccess-file in the magento.dev root directory.
- Set Magento in development mode
- Clearing the cache manually and running `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` again

Most guides and forum posts tell me to run: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` but I'm not sure, if I'm doing it correctly.

OS: OSX 10.11.2

MAMP version: 3.5

PHP version: 7.0

Apache version: 2.4.16

MySQL version: 5.6.25

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm on 2.2.2 installed on CentOS server. Nothing on this page works. To have any styling I must run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f ` and wait 80 seconds.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**SOLUTION # 1 (IF YOU WANT TO EDIT XML FILE)**

I would like you to download Magento 2 zip from `magentocommerce.com/download`, create new **db** in **phpmyadmin**, extract zip in **htdocs** folder. Install Magento 2 but do not use **localhost** use **127.0.0.1** in store URL and admin URL. After successful installation **DO NOT** run magento.

Now we are going to clear / delete caches and sessions of Magento 2. Go to following paths and delete everything:

```
ROOT > var > cache > *DELETE ALL*
ROOT > var > page_cache > *DELETE ALL*
ROOT > var > session > *DELETE ALL*
```

When Magento 2 is not in production mode, it will try to create symlinks for some static resources on local server. We have to change that behavior of Magento 2 by going to edit `ROOT > app > etc > di.xml` file. Open up `di.xml` in your favorite code editor, find the `virtualType name="developerMaterialization"` section. In that section below, you will find an item `<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">` which needs to be modified. You can modify it by changing the following content:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

To:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Now last step, also delete old files generated in `ROOT > pub > static > DELETE ALL EXCEPT .HTACCESS`

I personally tried it on my localhost using MAMP, EasyPHP DevServer, Xampp and Wampp and successfully installed and using Magento 2.
For further you can check out this link:
[Magento 2 CSS and JavaScript not loading from correct folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder)

**SOLUTION # 2**

Install Composer. Now I would like you to download Magento 2 zip from `magentocommerce.com/download`, create new **db** in **phpmyadmin**, extract zip in **htdocs** folder. Install Magento 2 but do not use **localhost** use **127.0.0.1** in store URL and admin URL. After successful installation **DO NOT** run magento.

Now we are going to verify Composer installation, Deploy static content, clear / flush Magento cache and reindex the Magento 2 blocks. To perform all above actions, press WINDOWS KEY + R to open RUN dialog and type “cmd” to open Command Prompt.

Type “**cd PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO2_FILES**” to enter in Magento 2 ROOT directory.

Now to verify Composer installation in above directory, type “**composer install**”.

> If you get any error in this step, please check your Composer
>   installation

In this step, we are setting up static content to deploy on our Magento store. To perform this, type “**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**”.

> If you get any error, check your PHP.EXE and PHP.INI Environment
>   Variable

Clear / Flush Magento cache by typing “**php bin/magento cache:flush**” in CMD.

And finally, to Reindex Magento Static Blocks type “**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**”.

You are done with successful installation of Magento 2.

Comment: Answer has been edited.

Comment: Greate! I tried the solution 1 and It works for me.. Thanks Khatak sb

Comment: Welcome @MuhammadAzeem

Comment: @RajaKhoury You're welcome!

Comment: Solution 1 works for me! Thank youu very much!!

Answer (score 5):

Try to run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

And if it gives any error while running this command, like file missing as you already said ,then compare your project file structure with fresh `magento2` file structure . If any file missing in your project then copy appropriate file into your project.

And if you got any other error then post error in your question so someone can answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. I'll do that. Where exactly and how do I run this command?

Comment: @Skovsgaard you can run this command from your terminal but make sure that you are in magento2 directory from terminal

Comment: It seems like no files are missing. The installed Magento obviously contains more files though which are related to the installation process. I get this error: `Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento.dev/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php on line 64` after running `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` in the root directory.

Comment: I wasn't really helpful. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `intl` extension is not loaded in you console version of php. Please verify that you use same version/settings for apache and cli version of php.

MacOsX has preinstalled version of php and some packages that install php do not change symlink for terminal session. As result you can have different version of php installed in same time.

PS: I propose to use vagrant on Mac OS. it is working pretty well if use nfs for file sharing

Comment: Aha! The preinstalled php (cli) is only 5.5.30. Preinstalled Apache is 2.4.16 (I don't know how to check MAMP's apache-version if MAMP also install Apache separately). So I have to update the preinstalled version to 7 and also install intl extension (cli or mamp?)?
Vagrant seem too advanced for a noob like me.

Comment: I cannot answer Mac-specific questions but there are at least two ways to check your PHP version: `php -v` (which shows what version PHP commands run as) and using a [phpinfo.php](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/optional.html#install-optional-phpinfo), which shows what version of PHP the web server runs.

Comment: Okay, so MAMP runs PHP 7 and Apache 2.2.29. My local machine runs PHP 5.5.30 and Apache 2.4.16. So next step is to update the local machine's PHP to 7?

Comment: Please try use full path to php7 binary

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, prune these directories:

```
rm -rf pub/static/*    # DO NOT DELETE .htaccess
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

This will work if you've got broken symlinks in those dirs.

Comment: .htaccess should never be deleted. I also did this mistake and wasted hours

Answer (score 1):

> clear page_cache, di ,view_process, cache

then give proper permission to folders and files.

then run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` from your root folder.

check pub/static.

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: Where and how do I run `clear page_cache, di ,view_process, cache`? 

Its a local installation, so as admin super of my computer I have all permissions read/write permissions. Are there any other permissions I'm not aware of?

Comment: if you are using local than give full permission to root-folder

Comment: all folders are in var/ clear all folders and give full permission to folder.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed `composer` and run `composer init` in magento2 directory?
If not, try it then run command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Composer is installed on my machine, yes, but I didn't use it for installing Magento 2. I simply just downloaded the .zip from their website, unpacked and installed. If i run `composer init` composer asks me to set up composer.json config, so I guess that won't help.