# Magento 2: Nginx pub/static not autogenerating, only works with command line static-content:deploy

Tags: magento2, static-content, command-line

I have tried many of the solutions from: [Local installation of Magento 2 doest not generate files in the pub/static folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95991/local-installation-of-magento-2-doest-not-generate-files-in-the-pub-static-folde) and similar posts:

I am in developer mode (verified in command line, and I can see error messages on the page for php). I am running Nginx with php-fpm from a 16.04 Ubuntu in vmware.

So far I've tried:

1. `chmod -R 777` on the `var` and `pub` folders
2. `chown -R www-data:www-data` on the `var` and `pub` folders, I've also tried them as owned by `root` with `777` perms.
3. tried the suggestion about changing from Symlink to Copy in `app/etc/di.xml` file
4. `pub/static.php` and `pub/static/.htaccess` I can verify exist and are correct

So I go to the browser (and my browser has cache disabled in network tab) and load a frontend or admin page and none of the `pub/static` file stuff is generated, the page loads but with no css, js, etc.

If I delete the `pub/static` I can re-generate them with `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and that works fine, but the issue is that anytime I make a change to a template file or js file, I have to delete `pub/static` and run that command which is very slow and not practical for development. So my questions are:

1. Any suggestions?
2. Could this have to do with how I have the owner and group of the Magento files? I am not sure how that should be. It seems like php-fpm runs as `www-data` but I'm not 100% sure about that, I am not good with linux.
3. Could it have to be with the user that I use when running `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`? Which user should that be in command line? Usually I run it as `root`. But as I mentioned, I've manually changed the pub and var folders and files to `www-data` but it doesn't help.
4. Or maybe it has to do with how I have the Mage Root set? I'm using the default `nginx.conf` file included, and have mage root set like: `set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/magento2;` (my magento 2 files and folders are in that directory)

Comment: What are you using to save your changes?  To my knowledge you can use this command line interface, Grunt, or Gulp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0) Verify, Are content of js/css files is cached in a browser?

1) Install xdebug and try to debug pub/static.php

2) I am using www-data groups and magento user and 777 for static files.

3) see 2). Do not use `root` to run static files deploy and do not run it in developer mode. Also, you need clean pub/static folder after `setup:static-content:deploy` running, because its  break automatic redeploy.

4) It looks right

Comment: thank you, so I did step 1 about using xdebug and found that pub/static.php was not being used. So I compared my nginx conf to the sample one that comes with Magento, and found that I had accidentally changed the root from  root $MAGE_ROOT/pub; to root $MAGE_ROOT; without the pub

Answer (score 0):

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` : commmand require to execute if modify files like **.css** **.html** **.js** inside **web** folder.

It not require to execute after modify any **.phtml** template or **layout** file.

If you are change in **phtml** or **layout** file, changes not applying then you have to just clean cache using command

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Note :** No need to re-generate pub/static after change in phtml file just need to clean cache if require.

Comment: setup:static-content:deploy : commmand  is not required