# Configuring Site having Issue

Tags: magento2

I have configured one site. But it is going like http://m2.com.test/static/frontend/conns/theme/en_US/applications/css/creditapp.css

why it is not taking from pub folder ?

Comment: try to run, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: yes.. after that nly getting like this

Comment: Delete all the folders and files except .htaccess in pub directory. For more information, check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95991/local-installation-of-magento-2-doest-not-generate-files-in-the-pub-static-folde

Comment: tried . but didnt get result